# Calling function from smart contracts after connection using connectWallet SDK react native

Tags: web3js

I have connected my react native app to metamask using wallet connect sdk now I want to call functions from a smart contract which is deployed on the binance test net. I was thinking I could achieve this using the ethers library however I am having trouble on providing ethers with a proivder